# Datepicker or other Jquery goodness inside modal window

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am able to generate the modal windows, as well as normal datepicker or autocomplete widgets from jquery, but what happens when I need to load a form inside a modal and datepicker or autocomplete be available inside the form?

It seems that the binding to the fields is tied to the window in the background. Can anyone please suggest a method to achieve this?

Thanks!

Basically I have the following code, the idea is that when I use datepicker without any modal windows it works fine. But the moment something goes into the modal, then nothing works (as I think is a new window altogether)

```
<div id="modal-container"></div>
<div id="modal">
  <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
</div>
which then are called upon with Ajax

$(function(){

  $("#article_edited_on").datepicker();

  var $modal = $('#modal'),
      $modal_close = $modal.find('.close'),
      $modal_container = $('#modal-container');

  $('a[data-remote]').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(e, xhr, settings){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, text/html, ' + settings.accepts.html);
  });

  $('a[data-remote]').live('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    $modal
      .html(data)
      .prepend($modal_close)
      .css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 40)
      .show();
    $modal_container.show();
  });

  $('.close', '#modal').live('click', function(){
    $modal_container.hide();
    $modal.hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If, when you say 'load a form inside a modal', you mean that you are dynamically loading the form using AJAX, then you will need to initialize the fields used for datepickers/autocomplete immediately after the load is completed.

Comment: Thanks belugabob, but not sure what you mean by this. Sorry, just a noob.

Comment: Can you put together a simple example of your code, so that we can confirmat that we've understood your explanation correctly.

Comment: @belugabob: edited question again, please see at start of js fro datepicker.

Comment: Ok, is `#article_edited_on` an element in the html that is loaded by the AJAX call? If so, you will need to move the datepicker initialisation to just before `$modal_container.show();' so that the element is available to initialise. Does this make sense?